Remotion Error: Module "remotion" has no exported member 'OffthreadVideo'
I am using remotion for my video editor and now I am facing new issue Module "remotion" has no exported member 'OffthreadVideo'., earlier it was working fine.
import { AbsoluteFill, OffthreadVideo, staticFile } from "remotion";

export const VideoWithText: React.FC<{
  link: any;
}> = ({ link }) => {
  const loacFileUrl = staticFile(link);
  return (
    <AbsoluteFill>
      <OffthreadVideo
        src={loacFileUrl}
        // Rest property
      />
    </AbsoluteFill>
  );
};


I explored and resolved the error by importing Video from
import {Video} from 'remotion'; instead import { OffthreadVideo } from "remotion";
So here is my working code:
import { AbsoluteFill, Video, staticFile } from "remotion";

export const VideoWithText: React.FC<{
  link: any;
}> = ({ link }) => {
  const loacFileUrl = staticFile(link);
  return (
    <AbsoluteFill>
      <Video
        src={loacFileUrl}
        // Rest property
      />
    </AbsoluteFill>
  );
};

